# MDL Tabs without MDL Layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, material-design-lite

I really need ONLY MDL Tabs, but [MDL](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section) won't let me split it from MDL Layout!

I tried [MDC](https://material.io/components/web/catalog/tabs/), but or I am a completely dumb person or using it through JavaScript + WebPack, importing and bundled and such, just won't work (you can guess the conclusion I took).

So, that's it. If somebody could post a code for me to understand and use like a 2 years old child, I'd be completely happy.